# How to implement date picker as Listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, datepicker

I want to implement a horizontal ListView in which i want to display 6 consecutive dates starting from current date.How to do that ?

Comment: To do this , you can use custom dialog which may be great and easy to use

Comment: I use a custom dialog.I want to display date inside that custom dialog

Answer (score 0):

code for getting 6 consecutive dates

```
      DateList = new ArrayList<String>();


      /// getting dates 
      Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(new Date());
      for(int i1 = 0;i1<5;i1++){
          if(i1 == 0){
              cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);  
          }else
          cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); 


          SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");

          String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

          DateList.add(date);





      }
```